# How do I implement a tree in rust where nodes are aware of their parent and children

Tags: rust, tree, refcell

I've been trying to implement this with `Rc<RefCell<>>` and such things but i always run into issues can anyone provide me with a link to  an example implementation?\

This is what i've tried:

```rust
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}
```

Most of the issues that i have faced come from the fact that a node refers to it's parent but it's parent also refers to the node.

Note: I haven't included functions such as add children because it is straight forward: Create the child that has an `Rc::clone()` to it's parent node and then push the child onto the children field of the parent node.

Comment: You should probably use [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) instead of `Rc` for the parent, other than that your definition looks ok for a first attempt. Without further info on where exactly you got stuck we can't really help you any further. Maybe you want to read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) which covers the topic of doubly linked lists of which trees are just a generalization of.

Comment: https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Rust/blob/master/src/data_structures/b_tree.rs may help